# Finding feasible solution s.t. value of objective function is greater than $248$.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I was asked the following question in examination :

> Using the simplex method ,verify that following problem is unbounded
>
> and hence  find a feasible solution for which the value of the following objective function is greater than $248.$ :
>
> maximize :
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2x_1+3x_2$ subject to ,
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_1-x_2+x_3\leq 2$
>
> $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-3x_1+x_2\leq4$  ,$~~~~~~~~~x_1,x_2\geq0$

I got how to show unboundedness,but can't get how to find a feasible sol$^n$ for which value of objective function is greater than $248.$

Kindly help ..

Answer (score 0):

If you choose $x_1=x_2=t$ and $x_3=0$, then the value of the objective function will be equal to $5t$, and all the constraint will be satisfied. So if you need greater value than $248$, then it is enough to choose $t > 248/5$.